# Ошибка при добавлении зависимости

Tags: android, gradle

Когда пытаюсь

```
compile 'org.solovyev.android:checkout:0.7.5@aar'
```

выходит ошибка:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'E:\AndroidPack\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+@aar'
    compile('com.mikepenz.materialdrawer:library:0.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'org.solovyev.android:checkout:0.7.5@aar'

}
```

LOG:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAnjlabAndroidIabV3Library1028Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikepenzIconicsLibrary073Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikepenzMaterialdrawerLibrary095Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgSolovyevAndroidCheckout075Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\skull\AndroidStudioProjects\CryptoMessenger\app\src\main\java\su\my.my\tictac\auth\verna.java
Warning:(133, 11) unreachable catch clause
thrown type FileNotFoundException has already been caught
Warning:(232, 11) unreachable catch clause
thrown type FileNotFoundException has already been caught
C:\Users\skull\AndroidStudioProjects\CryptoMessenger\app\src\main\java\su\my.my\tictac\auth\vernadubl.java
Warning:(159, 11) unreachable catch clause
thrown type FileNotFoundException has already been caught
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
      com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
      org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command   'E:\AndroidPack\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 12.276 secs
Information:1 error
Information:3 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: А вы архив скачали и добавили в проект?

Comment: нет, просто  compile 'org.solovyev.android:checkout:0.7.5@aar'
он автоматически не скачивается в этом случае?

Comment: Вроде как надо вот отсюда скачать его https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/solovyev/android/checkout/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно посмотреть в Gradle.app раздел

```
dependencies {

}
```

В моем случае там было обнаружено 2 аналогичных пакета. Из-за этого не компилировалось и выводилось ошибка com.android.dex.DexException:

Answer (score 2):

Суть ошибки здесь:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService

Некоторые из библиотек содержат в себе код из стандартной библиотеки биллинга Google Play. Либо просто несовместимы между собой.

Comment: А как это можно решить? не причинив "вред" проекту